# Making grid in WPF using loops dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an issue using a grid programatically in WPF. I'm trying to add a grid with columns and rows to my window, but I want to do it in C# code, not in XAML. I've made a class called *Playboard* in which I want to add a grid and columns/rows. The problem is the grid is not added to the window. I tested it using grid.showlines property, but nothing shows up.

```
class PlayBoard
{
   public Grid playGrid;

    public PlayBoard(int width, int height)
    {
        playGrid = new Grid();
        playGrid.Width = width-20;
        playGrid.Height = height-20;

        for (int i = 0; i < (playGrid.Height/10); i++)
        {
            var myRowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
            myRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(10);
            playGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(myRowDefinition);

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < (playGrid.Width / 10); j++)
        {
            var myColumnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
            myColumnDefinition.Width = new GridLength(10);
            playGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(myColumnDefinition);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code I use in MainWindow class in MainWindow constructor:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    PlayBoard board;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        board = new PlayBoard((int)PlayWindow.Width, (int)PlayWindow.Height);
        board.playGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Window` requires content. You can add the `Grid` to the window by assigning it to the Window's `Content` property.

```
this.Content = board.playGrid;
```

It seems that you're actually trying to create what is referred to as a `UserControl`. A `UserControl` is a custom control that is made up of other controls. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx).